# How would I print the fav_genre field for a specific user

Tags: python

So the code below saves the variables username pass etc into a text file with the colons to separate each field. say I wanted to print out the favourite genre of a particular user, how would that be possible as my attempts so far to do so have failed. this is all in python btw. ive edited to add my attempt but its not woking.Any ideas??

```
usrFile_write = open(textfile, 'a')
usrFile_write.write(username + ' : ' + password + ' : ' + name + ' : ' + dob + ' : ' + fav_artist + ' : ' + fav_genre + ' : ' + '\n')
print('New Account Created!')
print()
usrFile_write.close()
Menu()
```

my attempt:

```
textfile = 'user_DB.txt'
username = 'dj'
def getUsersFavouriteGenre():
    with open(textfile, 'r') as textIn:
        for line in textIn:
            information = line.split(' : ')
            if information[0] == username:
                return information[5]
    return 'Failed to find user.'

getUsersFavouriteGenre()
```

Comment: What are the errors? What does it output that is unintended?

Comment: You could add yourself some debugging, e.g. print the `information` list for every line and investigate the output.

Comment: if the name exists in the database the question repeats itself whereas if it doesn't it says 'user doent exist...'

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good. I'm assuming the issue is your program doesn't output anything, in which case the only issue I see is change your last line `getUsersFavouriteGenre()` to `print(getUsersFavouriteGenre())`

If you are getting a specific error or undesired output then you can let us know and we can help you more specifically.

Comment: at the moment nothing prints out when the code is run even with your correction

Comment: @user8941770 Could you edit your answer to show the actual contents of `user_DB.txt`? Then we could run your code ourselves. If it's printing nothing then that means your code IS finding a line where `information[0] == 'dj'` but there is nothing for the `information[5]` value (because if it couldn't find the `information[0] == 'dj'` then it would print `'Failed to find user.'`